# Unable to locate text from web page using Selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape amazon reviews for a certain product, but I am unable to locate the text for the ratings using selenium. But the same thing is easily **scraped** using soup.

Link to page:
https://www.amazon.in/BenQ-inch-Bezel-Monitor-Built/product-reviews/B073NTCT4R/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_paging_btm_next_2?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=39

Here is my code using Soup:

```
 link='same link as mentioned above'
 url=requests.get(link).content
 bs=soup(url,'html.parser')
 for i in bs.find_all('span',{'class':'a-icon-alt'}):
    print(i.text.split(' ')[0])
```

##Output
4.3
5.0
1.0
5.0
2.0
4.0
1.0
5.0
5.0
5.0
5.0
5.0
5.0

Here is my code using Selenium:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

link='link to the above mentioned page'
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.a-icon-alt'):
     print(i.text)
```

I am unable to get the same results with Selenium, all I get are blanks equivalent to the number of items present on that page. I have also tried using XPath and class_name but didn't get the required response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the review ratings Induce `WebDriverWait` and wait for `presence_of_all_elements_located`() and use `get_attribute("innerHTML")` instead of text

**Code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

link='https://www.amazon.in/BenQ-inch-Bezel-Monitor-Built/product-reviews/B073NTCT4R/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_paging_btm_next_2?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=39'
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".a-icon-alt")))
for i in elements:
    print(i.get_attribute("innerHTML").split(' ')[0])
```

**Output on console :**

```
4.3
5.0
1.0
5.0
2.0
4.0
1.0
5.0
5.0
5.0
5.0
5.0
5.0
```